How to get username of API caller in wso2 apim in Basic Authorization?
As you know we have 3 types of Authorization in WSO2 API management API Call: Basic, ApiKey, OAuth
I need to extract username of API caller. I used this way as you can see in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78538232/7318224
<log level="custom">
  <property name="USER_NAME" expression="$ctx:api.ut.userName">
</log> 

But, This code only works if we use OAuth Authentication. So If we use Basic Authentication, this property will be NULL. Do you have any solution for that? I search the easiest way. Thank you!

You can use following property for this.
<log level="custom">
  <property name="USER_NAME" expression="$ctx:api.ut.userId">
</log>

Full set of properties.
api.ut.consumerKey
api.ut.userId
api.ut.api_version
api.ut.api
api.ut.version
api.ut.api_type
api.ut.hostName
api.ut.application.name
api.ut.application.id
api.ut.userName


Thanks. Your comment was true, I evaluated it. But Could you say all properties of $ctx? Is there a good source for that? @ycr
